# Publishing Scala project to local repository?

Tags: sbt

I'm trying to publish a project into my local repository with sbt.

This is my **build.sbt** file

```
name := "myProject"

organization := "co.myorganization"

version := "2.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

sbtPlugin := true
```

This is my `publishLocal` command output:

```
[info] :: delivering :: co.myorganization#myProject;2.0 :: 2.0 :: release :: Thu May 15 14:57:24 COT 2014
```

All seems to work fine but in my other project I'm getting this error when I try to use it as a dependency like so:

```
"co.myorganization" % "my-project"  % "2.0"
```

Error output:

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: co.myorganization#my-project;2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: co.s4n#s4n-autenticacion;2.0: not found
[error] Missing task key: scalaInstance
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.sbtidea.Settings.logErrorAndFail(Settings.scala:11)
    at org.sbtidea.Settings$$anonfun$task$1.apply(Settings.scala:24)
    at org.sbtidea.Settings$$anonfun$task$1.apply(Settings.scala:24)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.sbtidea.Settings.task(Settings.scala:24)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$.projectData(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:163)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:88)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:87)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:278)
    at scala.collection.immutable.RedBlackTree$.foreach(RedBlackTree.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap.foreach(TreeMap.scala:202)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.collect(TraversableLike.scala:278)
    at scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap.collect(TreeMap.scala:48)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$.doCommand(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:87)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$$anonfun$org$sbtidea$SbtIdeaPlugin$$ideaCommand$2.apply(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:45)
    at org.sbtidea.SbtIdeaPlugin$$anonfun$org$sbtidea$SbtIdeaPlugin$$ideaCommand$2.apply(SbtIdeaPlugin.scala:45)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:60)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:62)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:95)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:179)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:100)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are you adding your project with `addSbtPlugin` or as a normal dependency?

Comment: I was adding it as a normal dependency. It was my fault. So I remove sbtPlugin := true and voila! It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build the project as plugin `sbtPlugin := true` it will add an extra information about the sbt version.

You have to add these kind of artefacts with `addSbtPlugin`, additionally because you've overridden default Scala version for the plugin you'd have to add it to the `addSbtPlugin` method:

```
addSbtPlugin("co.myorganization" % "myproject" % "2.0", "0.13", "2.11")
```

assuming that you want to add your plugin to Sbt version 0.13 and Scala 2.11.

When doing plugins better stick with default version of Scala.

If your intention is not to have a plugin remove `sbtPlugin := true` from your `build.sbt`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to add your local repository to the resolvers list?

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at file(
    Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository").toURL.toString
```